# using ssh and rsync in makefile

Tags: makefile

I came across the following code in a makefile.

```
ifdef MYBUILD                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.PHONY: rsync all, clean
all:  rsync
  ssh $(MYBUILD) make -C cs/src
clean:  rsync
  ssh $(MYBUILD) make -C cs/src $@
rsync:
  ssh $(MYBUILD) mkdir -p cs/src
  rsync -Cavuz . $(MYBUILD):cs/src
```

I can't seem to understand what ssh and rsync would be doing in a make system? Can someone explain the above usage.

Comment: Do you understand what `ssh` and `rsync` do?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - ssh is secure shell to log into a remote machine. rsync is to synchronize source code on two different machines?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - still don't get their use in this context.

Comment: They're operating on a remote machine.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - I have my source code on my local machine.

Comment: Did you write the makefile?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - No I didn't. It is a very old file that I am supposed to maintain.

Comment: Did you ask whoever wrote the makefile?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - person not in the company anymore. :)

Comment: Do you have any purpose for those targets?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - not that I can figure out currently. First cut I want to get it compile on my local Linux system.

Comment: Are you using a source code revision system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Makefile allows you to run building on a build machine rather than your localhost. (Whether or not this is needed, you need to decide).

The `all` target will first have the `rsync` target performed and then will `ssh` to the remote system and run `make` there.

The `rsync` target will make sure your local source files are copied to the build machine.

If you want to test it, set up a separate build machine with SSH access using keyfiles, put that machine to some nice address or domain name (I will use 192.168.1.111) and then run

```
make MYBUILD="192.168.1.111"
```

Comment: It seems the OP is looking for a way to build on his local machine. You should mention that if OP wants to build locally, he can definitely run `make MYBUILD=localhost`. This is assuming he is not allowed to modify the `Makefile`.

Comment: The way I see it he's trying to understand "What the heck does this code do?" and "Why is there `ssh` and `rsync` when `make` is all about building software *(I know that last assumption is false BTW)*